# Run GTX 770 at 5760x1080 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, graphics, gaming

I just purchased an NVIDIA GTX 770, and I would like to run games (e.g. Dirt 3) across all 3 monitors.

I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. If I could force Windows to treat all 3 monitors as one, I'd imagine Dirt 3 would let me choose a higher resolution.

Is there software that can do this?

I keep running across this "Nvidia Surround" but I can't find anywhere to download it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to setup Surround from the NVIDIA Control Panel. If you right-click on your desktop as though you were going to change the resolution you should see it in your menu. If you don't have it go and install the latest NVIDIA drivers from their website: http://www.geforce.com/drivers.